# Check if file exists from string

Tags: java

This is the code I use when I try to read some specific text in a *.txt file:

```
public void readFromFile(String filename, JTable table) {

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

        try {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            String a,b,c,d;
            for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
            {
              a = bufferedReader.readLine(); 
              b = bufferedReader.readLine(); 
              c = bufferedReader.readLine(); 
              d = bufferedReader.readLine(); 
              table.setValueAt(a, i, 0);
              table.setValueAt(b, i, 1);
              table.setValueAt(c, i, 2);
              table.setValueAt(d, i, 3);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //Close the reader
            try {
                if (bufferedReader != null) {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

And it is called in this way:

```
readFromFile("C:/data/datafile.txt", table1)
```

The problem is the following: the 1st time I open the program the *.txt file I'm going to read does not exist, so I thought I could use the function `exists()`. I have no idea about what to do, but I tried this:

```
if(("C:/data/datafile.txt").exists()) {
readFromFile("C:/data/datafile.txt", table1)
}
```

It is not working because NetBeans gives me a lot of errors. How could I fix this?

Comment: As it stands, you could simply return from the exception handler for FileNotFoundException.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`String` has no method named `exists()` (and even if it did it would not do what you require), which will be the cause of the errors reported by the IDE.

Create an instance of [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) and invoke [`exists()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29) on the `File` instance:

```
if (new File("C:/data/datafile.txt").exists())
{
}
```

Comment: beaten me to the answer in about 10 seconds :)

Answer (score 9):

Note: This answer use classes that aren't available on a version less than Java 7.

The method `exists()` for the object *String* doesn't exist. See the [String documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for more information. If you want to check if a file exist base on a path you should use `Path` with `Files` to verify the existence of the file.

```
Path file = Paths.get("C:/data/datafile.txt");

if(Files.exists(file)){
   //your code here
}
```

Some tutorial about the `Path` class :  [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html)
And a blog post about [How to manipulate files in Java 7](http://www.java7developer.com/blog/?p=334)

**Suggestion for your code**:
I'll point to you the tutorial about [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) as it could be useful to you. I also want to bring your attention on [Files#readAllLines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) as it could help you reduce the code for the reading operation. Based on this method you could use a for-each loop to add all the lines of the file on your `JTable`.

Comment: Files manipulation in Java 7 has become quite effective IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this code to check if the file exist

Using **java.io.File**

```
File f = new File(filePathString);
if(f.exists()) { /* do something */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to give it an actual File object. You're on the right track, but NetBeans (and java, for that matter) has no idea what '("C:/data/datafile.txt")' is.

What you probably wanted to do there was create a `java.io.File` object using that string as the argument, like so:

```
File file = new File ("C:/data/datafile.txt");
if (file.exists()) {
   readFromFile("C:/data/datafile.txt", table1);
}
```

Also, you were missing a semicolon at the end of the `readFromFile` call. Im not sure if that is just a typo, but you'll want to check on that as well.

If you know you're only ever using this `File` object just to check existence, you could also do:

```
if (new File("C:/data/datafile.txt").exists()) {
   readFromFile("C:/data/datafile.txt", table1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ensure that you can read from the file, it might even be appropriate to use:

```
if(new File("C:/data/datafile.txt").canRead()){
    ...
}
```

as a condition, in order to verify that the file exists **and** you have sufficient permissions to read from the file.

[Link to canRead() javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canRead%28%29)